# como fazer o build e executar pela IDE um projeto maven

Tags: java, maven, wildfly, wildfly13

Boa tarde,

Estou tentando gerar uma aplicação para estudos utilizando maven, mas esta desastroso e muito frustrante.

estou tentando criar um projeto web utilizando o maven, porem não consigo por nada fazer com que ele seja executado, porem estou tentando fazer tudo pela IDE, ta tentei vários web servers e web containers, mas nenhum deles sobe de fato a aplicação.

tentei configurar o wildfly de forma tradicional, assim o projeto sobe normalmente, mas ao converter o msm para maven ele para de executar, o mesmo ocorre se eu criar o projeto como sendo um projeto maven webapp.

tentei acrescentar o plugin do wildfly e posteriormente o jetty e em nenhum dos casos obtive sucesso, ao tentar "maven>update project" ele nem ao menos baixa o server, consequentemente não o executa, o mesmo ocorre com o jetty e é claro se mantem o erro:

> Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type The superclass
>   "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" was not found on the Java Build Path

claramente devido a falta de um web server ou servlet container

segue meu pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>br.com.lsoft</groupId>
  <artifactId>gameapi</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>gameapi Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies> 

  <build>
    <finalName>gameapi</finalName>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>13.0.0.Final</version>
            <configuration>
                <port>8081</port>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

  </build>
</project>
```

com isso me resta algumas pergunta simples:

sempre que eu for trabalhar com maven eu sou obrigado a utilizar o cmd pra compilar e executar o projeto?
caso não seja, pq isso não foi demostrado na aula em questão, neste caso ja fica a sugestão pra refazer essa aula, ou criar uma a mais para este curso, ensinando como faze-lo.

ao analisar o "web.xml" criado percebi que o projeto foi criado co o padrão servlet 2.3, como faço pro projeto ser criado com uma versão posterior???
segue o web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Calma que toda build tool é assim. É catastrófico no começo. O importante é ser resiliente e se debruçar na documentação e exemplos de uso. Pela mensagem de erro, dá a entender que você criou uma aplicação *jsp* e está tentando roda-lá como desktop. Leia esse tutorial da Oracle e veja se lhe ajuda: [Building and Running a Java SE Application by Using Maven](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/Maven_SE/Maven.html)

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite.

Creio que a opção mais simples seja criando o projeto através do site de start do Spring Boot, no caso em que você mencionou o uso apenas do MAVEN, https://start.spring.io/ após você faz o download e importa um projeto do maven selecionando o diretório descompactado.

Comment: Olá Daniel, acha que criar um novo projeto e migrar **todas** as alterações do projeto atual seria o melhor caminho?

Comment: Olá André, eu mencionei criar um projeto do zero pois você mencionou que você está tentando criar, então passei o passo a passo que utilizo para projetos de testes, mas você pode criar um e comparar o pom com o seu e tentar encontrar as diferenças podendo assim ajustar e encontrar a possível falha.